# Trusted Signing 400 error with SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed error

Tags: azure, code-signing, trusted-signing

When trying to submit a signing request with Trusted Signing I get a 400 error along with a SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed error. I have read that this issue could be related to role assignments, incorrect credentials, or tenant connectivity, but I have checked all of these variables and confirmed that everything is correct. Are there any suggestions for what I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to caching of certificates. Add to your JSON "ExcludeCredentials": ["SharedTokenCacheCredential"]. To learn more go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet.